# SQL get active price from 2 column table using specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, price

How to select active price, the first priority is the season price, if it's within the date range then, choose the price from the season. But if it's not in the date range, then choose it from another table(TBL_ROOM_TYPE).

[image: pic 1]

```
 SELECT
  TBL_ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE,
  COALESCE(TBL_SEASON_TYPE_MAP.SEASON_PRICE, TBL_ROOM_TYPE.TYPE_PRICE) AS price
FROM
  TBL_ROOM_TYPE 
  left JOIN TBL_SEASON_TYPE_MAP ON TBL_ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE = TBL_SEASON_TYPE_MAP.ID_ROOM_TYPE
join  TBL_ROOM_SEASON on TBL_ROOM_SEASON.ID_SEASON=TBL_SEASON_TYPE_MAP.ID_SEASON
and (@ArrivalDate BETWEEN TBL_ROOM_SEASON.[START_DATE]  AND TBL_ROOM_SEASON.[END_DATE] )
```

so i want to change the price in id 1 and 3 to be the same as pic 1 [image: pic2]

[image: TBL_SEASON_TYPE_MAP]

[image: TBL_ROOM_SEASON]

[image: TBL_ROOM_TYPE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please work along these line and table names along with their images would help.

```
SELECT 
 R.ID_ROOM_TYPE
,CASE  
WHEN  START_DATE<'2018-03-18' AND END_DATE >'2018-03-18' THEN SEASON_PRICE 
ELSE TYPE_PRICE END AS PRICE
 FROM TBL_ROOM R 
LEFT JOIN TBL_ROOM_SEASON S ON S.ID_SEASON = R.ID_SEASON
LEFT JOIN TBL_ROOM_TYPE T ON T.ID_ROOM_TYPE = R.ID_ROOM_TYPE
```

[Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqwyC.png)

Thanks.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i'm not yet getting what i want to show, so this is what i want to show https://i.imgur.com/4q12OJ1.jpg, how to show it all of the the room price. Thank you

Comment: okay nevermind i have done it lol,it took me 3 days to get my brain work how to achieve it,i use the intersect and yes thank you for your answer too, i can solve problem with the season price

Comment: Thanks @Jueun. I am happy you got it.